# Merge accounts on two IMAP servers

Tags: imap

My organization offers us two email services (Exchange and Gmail for business, both with IMAP access) under the same name (i.e. I have one single email address and I get to choose to which server my emails are delivered). I was using Exchange but now want to switch to Gmail. Is there a tool to import all my emails to Gmail so that I won't lose my correspondence?

Comment: [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync).

Comment: Also important is to disable the exchange account (afterwards), as otherwise exchange may go "oh hey this account is local" and not deliver things over to gmail (or whatever middle layer is making the forwarding decision between exchange and gmail).

Comment: @n.st Yes that's exactly what I want. Works for me.